# how to json encode two arrays and use them in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

here is what i am trying to do.I want to retrieve all the names and details having a particular reference number.so i am using while loop. But i don't know how do i json encode those values and retrieve them so that i can use them in ajax so dispaly them.And the other problem is that i already have a json encoded array and i want to retrieve those values as well.So i want to retrieve two arrays using json encode.
here is the code-

```
$sql = "SELECT *  From (select * from tran ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 1) AS name  ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$rows1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$master_ref_no = $rows['master_tran_ref'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stk WHERE tran_ref = '$ref_no'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $tot = $row['tot'];
    $data[] = ["pname" => $name,"ptot"=>$tot];//but i dont know how do i retrieve this and use it in ajax.
}

$response = ["success" => true, "date" => $rows1['date'], "v_no" => $rows1['v_no'], "types" => $rows1['v_type']]; // this is working perfectly fine.  

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

And this is how i am using it in ajax to display in html table-

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "demopost.php",
   data: formData,
   success: function(response){   
        if (response.success) {
            $('#datepreview').val(response.date);
            $('#v_nopreview').val(response.v_no);
            $('#typepreview').val(response.types);
            $('#entrysavedmodal').modal('show');
        } else {
            alert("failure in");
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure out");
    }
});
```

So please help me out with how do i json encode all those values retrieved from while loop and include them along with the other array ,i.e. response and use them in ajax.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could just write both arrays in a "master" array: `$returnArray['response'] = $response; $returnArray['data'] = $data; echo json_encode($returnArray);`

Comment: and how do i use them in ajax to display the values?@Jeff

Comment: `$response = ["success" => true, "data" => $data];` there is no difference

Comment: but how do i call values inside variable data using through ajax?@SanzeebAryal

Answer (score 1):

JSON arrays can be multidimensional as well, so you could just stick your `$data` array in to your `$results` and pass it along, like so:

```
$response = ["data" => $data, "success" => true, "date" => $rows1['date'], "v_no" => $rows1['v_no'], "types" => $rows1['v_type']];
```

Then your output would have a structure like this:

```
{
    data: {
        0: {
            pname: value1
            ptot: value2
        },
        1: {
            pname: value3
            ptot: value4
        }
    },
    success: true,
    //rest of values here
}
```

So to access value3, for example, your jQuery would look like

```
results.data.1.pname
```

You could then loop over the `results.data` level to get all the pname/ptot pairs, or restructure it in your PHP code before you encode it.

Comment: but I dont know how many values will be there in my data array.Can you please edit my code and let me know how are you telling me to do this?@jason

Comment: Just replace your `$response` line with mine. You haven't shown what you want to do with the "data" variable, so I can't help there without more information.

Comment: see i want to retrieve all the information in the data variable and display them in a html table and for that i am using ajax.this is shown in my above code.so now my query is that how do i call those values stored inside data variable to display them in my table.As i dont know how many values there can be in my data variable.sometimes there can be 1 value and sometimes there can be 3 or 4 values.

Comment: for now i am calling response values like this ` $('#v_nopreview').val(response.v_no);` but i dont have any clue about how do i call data values .ANd the one which you suggested is not fine with me as i dont know how many values there can be in my data variable